# Xamarin.Forms Popup Dialog with custom view

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Popup dialog or Dialog in Xamarin.Forms but i am unable to find any reference or document to achieve this.

I want to show view on top of current page, something like this...
[image: MainPage]

[image: Dialog Box with custom view]

Currently i am focusing on iOS in Xamarin.Forms... Any code snippet or project reference is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

**Popup Page Plugin for Xamarin Forms**

*The plugin allows you to open any page as a popup.*

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/

Comment: How is it use in xamarin forms ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't Push to the ModalStack because it replaces the current page and you want to see the current page underneath.

So you have a few options here of create your own if you want complete customization or use a package such as: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs. They have a link to examples on that page.

Here is a quick customizable one if you want to roll your own.

```
<Grid IsVisible={Binding IsDialogShown}" BackgroundColor="Black" Opacity="0.7">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="500" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
       .. Controls in here (change this to grid or whatever you want)
   </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to popup layout in Xamarin Labs
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32373/how-to-implement-a-pop-up-window-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1):

[FormsPopup](https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup) can do the trick using Xamarin Forms

[image]